I'm on windows, working with SFML in C++, and when I zoom in or out, it doesn't click the cell under the mouse
It's a game-of-life so with a grid of squares. I did that we can draw on the grid by clicking the cell (left click). Also (with a view) you can move from side to side with right click and zoom in and out. I did found how to resolve the position issue for sliding, by changing the mouse coordinates with the distance difference, but I can't find how to solve it for the scrolling.
The sliding and zoom system works perfectly fine by itself though. It's just the position under the mouse which is incorrect.
I tried to do as I did for the sliding stuff but we don't have a distance difference to work with. At first I thought I didn't need to make changes on the coordinates and just convert them in screen or view mode but it doesn't work.
And I search and tried a lot of thing, and never found how to do that.
case sf::Event::MouseWheelMoved:
    movingView.zoom(1.f + event.mouseWheel.delta * 0.1f);

mouse = sf::Mouse::getPosition(window);
viewMouse = window.mapPixelToCoords(mouse);

if (event.mouseButton.button == sf::Mouse::Right)
{
     lastMouse = mouse;
     center += moveDiff;
     rightClickPressed = true;
}

if (rightClickPressed)
{
     moveDiff = (sf::Vector2f)(lastMouse - mouse);
                movingView.setCenter(sf::Vector2f(center + moveDiff));
}
if (leftClickPressed)
{
     viewMouse += movingView.getCenter() - movingView.getSize() / 2.f;
     gameOfLife.clickCell(viewMouse, E_pressed);
}


If you Google a bit you'll find tons of information on how to convert mouse/screen/view/world coordinates in sfml.

Alright, I found the solution, the only thing I didn't tried I guess...
just have to convert from screen to world with the correct view
window.mapPixelToCoords(mouse, movingView);

